# How to get mail sitting in Outbox to be sent out?

Tags: email, stock-email-app, outlook.com

I am using a Sony XPeria tablet with Android 4.1.2. I am using an ereader which can send email from within the app. If the tablet is not in Airplane mode, the emails go out fine. If the tablet is in airplane mode, the emails get queued in the outbox folder. When not in airplane mode, I open the stock email app and I see the emails int the outbox folder. However I see no option to send out the emails when I select the messages. When I resync, I get inbound messages but the outbound messages stay stuck in Outbox.

The only way I can send these emails is by selecting each message and forwarding it to myself (the recipient of these messages is myself). My mail server is outlook.com.

How do you force outgoing messages to be sent out?

Comment: (1) So the ereader has an email client? What is the name of this ereader? (2) Are you using the stock email app?

Comment: App uses OS's email functionality. Moon Reader.. why do you ask? I am using the stock email app.. as I mentioned.